# Валидация ASP.NET MVC на русском

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, валидация

Делал дома проект на локальной машине все валидационные сообщения работают, и они на русском. Выложил на хостинг, они все стали английским текстом. Как это можно исправить.
В конфиге прописано вот это

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="ru-RU" uiCulture="ru" />
```

У меня VDS хостинг, так что могу и на сервере настройки  менять. Читал на форумах что предлагали на стороне сервера поставить русский ASP.NET MVC, но мне кажется это не самое лучшее решение. Так же не уверен что он вообще на английский Windows поставится.

Можно, конечно, к каждому аттрибуту валидации прописать сообщение об ошибки на русском, но тут очень много где прописывать придётся. Так тоже могу сделать, но это уже если по-нормальному не получится.

**ОБНОВЛЕНО:**
Так понял что эти сообщения зашиты в самих аттрибутах. И если установлена английская версия, то они - английские.
Можно ли их руссифицировать?
Если нет, то попробую установить русский ASP.NET MVC на IIS. И тут тоже вопрос. Если сам Windows английский, то там даже такой возможности не было установить русский IIS или ASP.NET, такое вообще возможно?

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл решение.

Так как строки валидации жёстко прописаны в .NET Framework, То надо установить .NET Framework 4.6.1 Russian Language Pack.
Мне, что бы его установить на английский Windows потребовалось сначала установить Windows Server 2012 Russian Language Pack.

То есть эти две установки решили проблему.